# Calling JFileChooser twice in invokelater causes program not to exit

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread, invokelater

I am writing a program to collect information from two text files to add to tables in a database. In order to permit the user to select his own files I created a non-static method called `chooseFile()` that uses `JFileChooser` class to present a `showOpenDialog` (I've also tried it as a static method with the same results. If this sounds like I'm guessing, you're correct - I'm only so-so with programming).

My understanding is that calls to Swing classes in `main()` should be done using `invokelater`. This all worked fine (the JVM exits successfully) for one call to `chooseFile()`, but when I added a second call to `chooseFile()` the JVM keeps running indefinitely. However, the program exits normally with both calls to `chooseFile()` if I do so without using `invokelater`. Adding `System.exit(0)` after the second call in `invokelater` also allows the program to exit normally.

From what I have been able to gather, the program won't exit until all the (non-daemon) threads are closed. However, I thought that the purpose for using `invokelater` was to push all non-thread safe Swing related activities onto the EDT. Is using `System.exit(0)` the best practice here or is there something else I should know about?

Here is my SSCCE:

```
package ptMngr;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class ParticipantManager {

    private Path chooseFile() throws IOException{
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text Files", "txt","csv");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +
                chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
        }
        Path path = chooser.getSelectedFile().toPath();
        return path;
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){
    //        ParticipantManager pm =  new ParticipantManager();
    //        try {
    //            pm.chooseFile();
    //            pm.chooseFile();
    //
    //        } catch (IOException ex) {
    //            Logger.getLogger(ParticipantManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    //        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                ParticipantManager pm =  new ParticipantManager();
                try {

                    pm.chooseFile();
                    pm.chooseFile();
                    System.exit(0);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ParticipantManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ram Thank you for fixing the hanging bracket.

Comment: @Andrew I call the method the second time because I want the user to be able to open two separate files. I presume that for general application programming something like JFileChooser() would be designed to be called whenever a user wants to open/save a file and that any additional thread (if that is the correct term) created by the class would be handled. Hence, my question about System.exit(0).

Comment: *"I call the method the second time because I want the user to be able to open two separate files"*  Thanks for clearing that up.  Note that if the two files are in the same directory, it is easy to offer the user a single file chooser that allows selecting more than one file at a time (multi file selection).  Of course, that strategy might not fit for this user requirement (only you can tell that for sure).

Comment: 'Design' is not my strong point; I'm piecing it together as I go. The functionality of this program will be only to open these two files and create a DB with two tables. I have another program that prompts the user for an ID number and then queries the DB. I've been avoiding `JFrame` and using `JOptionPane`s so I don't have to bother with layout. One downside to this approach, however, is that there is no cue to the user that the program is still running, so I may need a `JFrame` anyways which should obviate the problem. But I think the question still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your call to `showOpenDialog(null)` you pass `null` as the parent component for the `JFileChooser`. It's been some time since I worked with `JFileChooser`, but I seem to remember, that a "magic" JFrame may be constructed, when `null` is passed in. It may be possible, that in this use case two "magic" JFrames are created and they prevent termination.

You may want to try to create a `JFrame` which serves as parent for both `JFileChooser`s so it does not create the automatic frames.

EDIT:

My first take would be this:

```
public static class ParticipantManager {
    JFrame frame;

    private JFrame getFrame() {
        if (frame==null) {
            frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(600, 400);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            // frame.setVisible(true); // <---- worked for me without this call too
        }
        return frame;
    }

    private void close() {
        frame.dispose();
    }

    private Path chooseFile() throws IOException{
        JFrame f = getFrame();
        ...
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(f);
    ...

    ...
                pm.chooseFile();
                pm.chooseFile();
                pm.close(); // <----- close the frame
    ...
```

Comment: I've come across suggestions like this as answers to related questions. I've tried it two different ways. Prior to posting this question I tried making the class extend JComponent  and called `chooser.showOpenDialog(ParticipantManager.this)` which compiles but doesn't solve the issue. Based on your post I created a JFrame in the invokelater block and passed it with `pm.chooseFile(frame)` and then used that frame as the parent with the same results. Am I interpreting your suggestions correctly? `System.exit(0)` would seem to be a simpler solution.

Comment: I adjusted my answer. I would create a JFrame, use that and dispose it when the file choosers are not needed any more. In my test it worked without making the frame visible (on Mac OS X El Capitan).

Comment: Or just call `JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();` when you are done with `JFileChooser`s, because they internally use that returned frame too.