# JFileChooser doesn't stop running

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I've been trying to use JFileChooser but I have the problem that the program doesn't stop running, here's my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class copiarArcivos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       JFileChooser();
    }

    public static void JFileChooser(){
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
        int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());
        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println("Selected file: " + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

Should I simply put a break at the end of the if?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create an empty JFrame. You can just use null:

```
//int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());
int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
```

Comment: Thanks, i thought that you needed one, but it seems i was wrong.

Comment: Regarding what the argument is for [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.String)). Used for placing the pop-up relative to its parent. Null places it relevant to the environment.

Comment: Warning, when using `null` as the parameter, a new `Frame` will be created which can be disposed with `JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();` when you are done with `JFileChooser`s and `JOptionPane`s. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33788138/calling-jfilechooser-twice-in-invokelater-causes-program-not-to-exit) for example.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the method name of JFileChooser in main method. and also in the declaration of this method. You can use JFileChooser2 instid of JFileChooser on both.